# Return formula in parent environment

Tags: r, attributes, formula, environment

If I have an R function that returns a `formula`, it is bound to the function's scope/environment. What can I do *from within the function* so that the returned formula does not have this environment attribute?

E.g.,

```r
myfun = function() {
    model = y ~ 1
    return(model)
}
```

Result:

```r
> myfun()
# y ~ 1
# <environment: 0x000001ffd94eca50>
```

One solution is modifying the attribute before return:

```r
myfun = function() {
    model = y ~ 1
    attr(model, ".Environment") = globalenv()
    return(model)
}
```

But this looks hacky, so is it really the best way?

Comment: What are you trying to use this formula for? iirc `lm` and others parse the formula and evaluate in their chosen environments anyway so I'm curious when the environment of the formula is important

Comment: ah, i should have double checked. will edit

Comment: @CalumYou If you are using the formula with `lm` and passing a data.frame, you're right that it probably doens't matter. But consider `foo <- function() {y <- rnorm(100);lm(myfun())}; foo()`. This will only work if the environment of the formula is the same as the `foo` function environment, not the `myfun` function environment.

Comment: I am making a function that builds and returns (lists of ) formulas that the user will use in the calling environment.

Comment: @MrFlick I guess it's right there in the docs but I'd never thought to use lm without a data argument! But it says: "If not found in data, the variables are taken from environment(formula), typically the environment from which lm is called." So ok, controlling the formula env is pretty key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might use the parent environment rather than the global enviroment

```
myfun <- function() {
    model <- y ~ 1
    environment(model) <- parent.frame()
    return(model)
}
```

That will create the environment from where you call it, bit `globalenv()` would also be fine if you prefer always the global environment.